# WSO2 Micro Integrator - Message Processors are Stuck After Do Server Stop and Start

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I am running WSO2 MI 4.1 in a cluster with two nodes.  After I re-enable all message forwarding processors in the Dashboard that are forwarding messages from RabbitMQs message store to an endpoint, each queue says it is running.  When I stop the server on one node wait for a short period of time and then start the same node back up and then repeat this on the second node, the message processors look enabled and all have an emabled state.  If I go to RabbitMQ, some of the queues are idle.  If I try to send a message to these queues the message just sits there in the queue. If I stop and start the message processor for the queue then the queue starts processing  messages.  This behavior happens with empty queues and queues that have messages in them.  Is this a bug or is there a better way to do a system restart?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the _meta_MSMP* files in the _system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.tasks/definitions/-1234/ESB_TASK/folder resolved this issue.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add more information about how did you find our the solution and why are you sure the described action resolved the described behavior?